# Writing Hardware Drivers, APIs, and Services

Tags: wcf, hardware, soa, robotics, hardware-interface

What books/blogs/podcasts etc... discuss patterns and best practices for designing software systems that interact with custom hardware and robotics? I am particularly interested in any books that would discuss strategies for writing a program that has to orchestrate and coordinate actions between several different custom hardware and robotics systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any particular blog or podcast based resources for this type of material.

However, it sounds like what you are doing would be a perfect fit for something like ROS (Robotics Operating System), an open-source robotics framework with a heavy emphasis on software engineering ideas.  While it's not a book or blog, the framework along with the associated community is a great way to learn about the hardware/software interaction necessary for robotics systems.

You can find the website at [ros.org](http://www.ros.org/)